# Spring Cloud Single Sign On but only if already logged in

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud

I've got a spring cloud oauth2 server up and running with jwt and a client which config looks like this

```
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class PortalApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PortalApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Component
    public static class LoginConfigurer extends OAuth2SsoConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void match(RequestMatchers matchers) {
            matchers.antMatchers("/**");
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                    .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
                .and()
                .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
        }

        private Filter csrfHeaderFilter() {
            return new OncePerRequestFilter() {
                @Override
                protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
                    CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
                    if (csrf != null) {
                        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", csrf.getToken());
                        cookie.setPath("/");
                        response.addCookie(cookie);
                    }
                    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
                }
            };
        }

        private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
            HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
            repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
            return repository;
        }
    }
}
```

This is all fine and the app redirects to the auth server and redirects back to the Portal app when done.

### Client number two

But now I've got another client which is a web shop.

If the user is logged in at the auth server then the web shop should display a bar in the top with links to the users previous orders and a profile.

If the user is NOT logged in, then nothing should happen until the checkout step where they will have to either login or create an account.

### Question

How can I auto login if I'm already logged in to the auth server, but allow anonymous users otherwise?

Can I somehow use the spring.oauth2.resource.userInfoUri to achieve this?

Comment: Isn't that a normal "if authenticated show this otherwise show that" use case? You don't *have* to authenticate the user for every request (your ant matcher is /**).

Comment: If I'm logged in at account.mydomain.com where the oauthserver is. If I then visit www.mydomain.com I would like to see that I'm logged in. But it shouldn't force the user to login since it's a public site. I'm not shure how to configure this. How can I make www.mydomain.com go check the auth server to see if I'm logged in?

Comment: You can't really do that in a back channel unless you control both domains - otherwise you would have to use the browser and get the user involved in the process. If you control both domains then you can add a CORS filter to the "auth" domain allowing your browser to ask it from the "www" domain about the currently authenticated user. If you know he is authenticated then you can safely redirect the browser to a /login endpoint on your "www" and get a cookie for that domain without further authentication.